# how can I identify usb devices in virtualbox?

Tags: usb, virtualbox, wine

I have a USB desktop laser, for which the MS Windows software doesn't run particularly well in Wine. So I tried VirtualBox 5.2.12, but I can't seem to get the USB device to be recognized. Wine would recognize the USB device.

The Windows VM is Windows 7, my OS is Ubuntu-Mate 18.04.

In VirtualBox I have tried settings for USB 1.1, USB 2.0, and USB 3.0, and I have installed the `virtualbox-ext-pack`. Im not sure what else to try. In the windows VM, the device manager states that the USB hub is "unrecognized".

Comment: Did you make sure your host user account is in the `vboxusers` group?

Comment: `sudo adduser $USER vboxusers` and reboot

Comment: evidently that had not previously been done. Ill check the results

Comment: well did that solve your problem? I can write a proper answer if it does

Comment: working 7/12's and college, ... I hoping to have this figured out soo, but Im so tired...

Answer (score 1):

Open your terminal and write the following command.

```
sudo su
```

Enter your password. Then run the following commands:

```
$ apt install virtualbox virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
$ apt install virtualbox-ext-pack
$ usermod -G vboxusers -a mir
```

In the last command, instead of `mir` use your admin account name such as nick, peter, etc.

Finally, reboot your PC.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced similar problem.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and Virtualbox 6.0.12.

## Problem:

I am trying to connect a wireless adapter(Alfa AWUS036H) to VirtualBox, but there was no USB device recognized.

[image: VirtualBox USB menu]

## Solution

Make sure your User is in the Vboxusers group. To do that, follow this:

1. Check what your User's username is:

   ```
   $ echo $USER
   ```

   The output of this command is your User's username.
2. Check all the groups that exist on your system:

   ```
   $ compgen -g
   ```

   Look for `vboxusers`.
3. Add your User to `vboxusers`:

   ```
   $ sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers $USER
   ```

For a demo solution check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=khmKavEV_74).

Comment: Thank you @user3140225 for editing. I will keep the format in mind. I really appreciate it. Means a lot to me.

Comment: No problem! You can read more about text formatting in [this editing guide](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help).